# poner un try catch desde el principio de mi aplicacion es correcto?

Tags: java, poo, try-catch

tengo un proyecto donde me piden realizar una conversión de monedas y temperatura y manejar try-catch, debemos usar JoptionPane para ingresar los datos quería saber si es correcto empezar el código con un try-catch para que cuando cierren la ventana de dialogo con la x de la esquina superior derecha no lance un error, adjunto el código, les pido que lo revise y me comenten si esta correcto, trate te manejar todos los errores que posiblemente pudieran surgir y esa fue la manera que se me ocurrió

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    while (!conversion.isEnd()) {

        String op = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "seleccione", "seleccion",
                JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, null,
                conversionOption.toArray(new String[0]), conversionOption);

        try {
            switch (op) {
                case "Monedas" -> {
                    boolean keepGoing;
                    do {
                        try {
                            keepGoing = false;
                            String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Ingrese el valor a convertir");
                            double receivedValue = Double.parseDouble(input);
                            strategy = new ConvertToDollar(receivedValue);
                        } catch (NumberFormatException n) {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Debe ingresar obligatoriamente un numero");
                            keepGoing = true;
                        } catch (NullPointerException nu) {
                            keepGoing = false;
                        }

                    } while (keepGoing);
                    try {
                        conversion.processConver(strategy);
                    } catch (NullPointerException ignored) {

                    }
                    int option = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Desea realizar otra conversion");
                    if (JOptionPane.OK_OPTION == option) {
                        conversion.isEnd();
                    } else {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Saliendo del programa");
                        conversion.setEnd();
                    }
                }

                // conversor temperatura
                case "Temperatura" -> {
                    boolean keepGoing2;
                    do {
                        try {
                            String input2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Ingrese el valor a convertir");
                            double receivedValue2 = Double.parseDouble(input2);
                            strategy = new Temperatura(receivedValue2);
                            keepGoing2 = false;
                        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Debe ingresar obligatoriamente un numero");
                            keepGoing2 = true;
                        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                            keepGoing2 = false;
                        }
                    } while (keepGoing2);

                    try {
                        conversion.processConver(strategy);
                    } catch (NullPointerException ignored) {
                    }
                    int option2 = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Desea realizar otra conversion");
                    if (JOptionPane.OK_OPTION == option2) {
                        conversion.isEnd();
                    } else {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Saliendo del programa");
                        conversion.setEnd();
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            conversion.setEnd();
        }


    }


}
```

Comment: Hola Valencia, en general, está bien, hay una cosita... en **case "Monedas"** el segundo **catch** tienes **keepGoing = false;** que carece de sentido, ya que en el try (antes del cast) haces lo mismo, por lo que en caso de entrar en el, ya estaría en "false", por otro lado, en **case "Temperatura"**, está al revés  por lo que deberías ponerlo delante del cast... osea, casi perfecto!!.

Comment: Un try-catch de ámbito amplio para **reaccionar** a ocurrencias localizadas de `null`, si consideras que no es importante retroalimentar con mayor detalle al usuario y/o el tratamiento es el mismo. Es reactivo (ya ocurrió el error) cuando puede ser preventivo (validar respuesta nula, por cualquier causa).

Comment: muchas gracias por sus respuestas